# Kendo Grid - Pop up Editor issue

Tags: kendo-ui

We are using pop up editor in the Kendo Grid control to edit the record.

My kendo grid has the below extra Controls as below.

1. Kendo dropdownlist
2. Div control
3. Add button
4. Remove button
5. A dropdown which has list of values that user will select and press the ADD button which is next to it.
6. then those values will be added to div control dynamically at runtime.
7. click on update in the editor, My controller updation action is getting fired.
8. Now i want to remove the items from the div tag using the Remove button. this time my controller update method is not firing.
9. I suspect that the changes in div is not firing the change event as the div control items dynamically added and removed.

How can i trigger the change event in the Remove button click function in jquery once i removed the div elements.

Please help me on this, trying this since 2 weaks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck.

Comment: You are going to need to post some code. The "Div Control " part is especially confusing without seeing it.